# sinusoidal waves for texture similarity

Tags: image-processing, wave, waveform-similarity

I created an algorithm that approximates the tiny image texture by a series of sinusoids. It is NOT Fourier or discrete cosine because the boundary is highly irregular.
I have each wave's frequency, amplitude, direction (angle relative to base vectors), and shift. Each texture is described by something like three waves - let's call this set of wave characteristics texture descriptor.

I need a differentiable similarity metric between texture descriptors to use as loss function.

Can I somehow use cross-correlation for it? Is there something better?